# Оптимизация загрузки сайта SPA SSR NEXT.JS

Tags: node.js, reactjs, nextjs, sequelize.js

Приложения которое мы разрабатываем ориентировано на просмотр словаря. 
Стек - (PostgreSQL, Sequelize, React, Next.js). 
У меня мало опыта в работе с этим стеком так что если я чего то не понимаю, то пожалуйста поправите меня.

На данный момент проблема в том что страница со всеми словами очень долго грузиться.
Слов - 1500 + описание для каждого слова, TTFB - 828 миллисекунд

Я думаю что в основном проблема в том что с сервера приходит большой размер контента. Я удалил цикл, который возвращает компоненты с контентом и в итоге получил 337 миллисекунд.

Я подумал может быть попробовать реализовать пагинацию, но заказчику это не подходит.

Скажите может кто-нибудь сталкивался с такой проблемой и сможет дать совет, как все это можно оптимизировать.

Код

```
import { Main } from "@/components/catalog/Common/Main";
import { useRouter } from "next/router";
import Link from "next/link";
import { Accourdion } from "@/components/catalog/UI/Accordion/Accordion";
import catalogSSPContainer from "@/container/catalog/catalogSSPContainer";
import catalogContainer from "@/container/catalog/catalogContainer";
import { DictionaryList } from "@/components/catalog/Common/Dictionary/DictionaryList";
import TemplatePage from "@/components/catalog/Common/TemplatePage";
import { Breadcrumb } from "@/components/catalog/UI/Breadcrumb/Breadcrumb";
import {
  Language,
  DictionaryCategory,
  DictionaryCategoryTo,
  Dictionary,
  DictionaryLangTo,
  DictionaryCategoryLangTo,
} from "@/db/models";
import LinkProvider from "@/components/catalog/UI/LinkProvider/LinkProvider";
import { VALUE_LANG, ROUTE_DREAMBOOK_DICTIONATY } from "@/utils/catalog/consts";

export const getServerSideProps = catalogSSPContainer(
  async ({ res, locale }) => {
    let localeInfo = await Language.findOne({ where: { code: locale } });

    let categorys = await DictionaryCategory.findAll({
      where: { parent_id: null },
      include: [
        {
          model: DictionaryCategory,
          as: "subcategories",
          include: [
            {
              model: DictionaryCategoryTo,
              separate: true,
              include: [
                {
                  model: Dictionary,
                  include: [
                    {
                      model: DictionaryLangTo,
                      separate: true,
                      where: { language_id: localeInfo.language_id },
                    },
                  ],
                },
              ],
            },
            {
              model: DictionaryCategoryLangTo,
              separate: true,
              as: "lang",
              where: { language_id: localeInfo.language_id },
            },
          ],
        },
        {
          model: DictionaryCategoryLangTo,
          separate: true,
          as: "lang",
          where: { language_id: localeInfo.language_id },
        },
      ],
      order: [
        ["category_id", "ASC"],
        [
          { model: DictionaryCategory, as: "subcategories" },
          "category_id",
          "ASC",
        ],
      ],
    });

    return {
      props: {
        data: {
          categorys: JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(categorys)),
        },
      },
    };
  }
);

export default catalogContainer(({ data }) => {
  const { locale } = useRouter();
  
  function SortArray(x, y) {
    return x.dictionary.dictionaryLangTos[0].name.localeCompare(
      y.dictionary.dictionaryLangTos[0].name,
      VALUE_LANG[locale],
      { ignorePunctuation: true }
    );
  }

  const localContent =
    require("@/locales/catalog/dreambook/dictionary/locales")[locale];

  return (
    <Main
      title={localContent.meta.title}
      description={localContent.meta.description}
      indicator={true}
    >
      <div className="breadcrumbs-wrapper breadcrumbs-wrapper-padding bg-6 d-none d-lg-block">
        <div className="container">
          <Breadcrumb breadcrumbs={localContent.breadcrumb} />
        </div>
      </div>

      <TemplatePage sideBar={localContent.sideBar}>
        <div
          className="mb-4-1 color-3 font-weight-bold"
          dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: localContent.banner }}
        ></div>

        {data.categorys.map(({ subcategories, lang, url }, index) => {
          return (
            <section
              className={`section ${
                index < data.categorys.length - 1 ? "mb-5-1" : "mb-4-1"
              } `}
              key={index}
            >
              <article>
                <h2
                  className="h2 mb-4-1 text-center font-weight-bold"
                  dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
                    __html: lang[0].name,
                  }}
                ></h2>

                <div className="types dictionary__types mb-2-1 d-flex flex-column">
                  {subcategories.map(
                    ({ category_id, lang }, index) => {
                      return (
                        <div key={index}>
                          <Link
                            href={`#subcategory-${category_id}`}
                            key={category_id}
                          >
                            <a
                              className={`font-weight-bold ${
                                index < subcategories.length - 1 ? "mb-1-1" : ""
                              } d-inline-block link-dotter`}
                            >
                              {lang[0].name}
                            </a>
                          </Link>
                        </div>
                      );
                    }
                  )}
                </div>

                <Accourdion
                  title={localContent.accardionCategory}
                  className="mb-4-1"
                >
                  <div
                    dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
                      __html: lang[0].description,
                    }}
                  ></div>
                </Accourdion>

                <LinkProvider className="d-flex flex-column mb-last-none">
                    {subcategories.map(
                      ({
                        category_id,
                        url: subcategory_url,
                        lang,
                        dictionaryCategoryTos,
                      }) => {
                        let urlItem = null;

                        {
                          url && subcategory_url ? (
                            (urlItem = `${ROUTE_DREAMBOOK_DICTIONATY}/${url}/${subcategory_url}`)
                          ) : (
                            <></>
                          );
                        }

                        return (
                          <div
                            key={category_id}
                            className="fix-anchor mb-5-1"
                            id={`subcategory-${category_id}`}
                          >
                            <h2
                              className={`h2 mb-3-1`}
                              dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
                                __html: lang[0].name,
                              }}
                            ></h2>

                            <DictionaryList
                              urlItem={urlItem}
                              dictionarys={dictionaryCategoryTos}
                            />
                          </div>
                        );
                      }
                    )}
                  </LinkProvider>
              </article>
            </section>
          );
        })}
      </TemplatePage>
    </Main>
  );
});
```

Comment: Надо найти самые долгие операции, как на стороне клиента, так и на сервера. Потом подумать, как их можно оптимизировать. Универсальной таблетки нет. И вот это зачем делать `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(categorys))`?

Comment: Спасибо. Буду скорей всего разговаривать с заказчиком насчет пагинации и проводить оптимизацию.

Если не выполняю JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(categorys)) то мне возвращается ошибка -
Error: Error serializing .categorys[0]  returned from  getServerSideProps  Please only return JSON serializable data types.

Решение нашел здесь
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66817759/next-js-error-serializing-res-returned-from-getserversideprops

Мне кажется что это решение костыльное, но у меня не было времени на решение данной проблемы.
Если вы сможете помочь мне, то буду благодарен